# Hibernate duplicate primary key on cascade insert with more than one entity (Unidirectional one-to-many)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a entity with a unidirectional @OneToMany as follows:

```
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_status")
    private Status status;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "childId")
    private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Which references this with the unidirectional @OneToMany (Last column of Parent entity):

```
public class Child{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long childId;

    private Date date;

    @Length(max = 255)
    private String description;

}
```

My problem is that on insert/update/delete of parent entity, any operation with the child entity fails.
Main issues are:

- On insert/update of parent with multiple children (with one child it works, but saves the child with id 2 instead of 1):

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.PRIMARY_KEY_DF ON PUBLIC.CHILD(CHILD_ID) VALUES ( /* 2 */ CAST(2 AS DECFLOAT) )"; SQL statement:
update child set child_id=? where child_id=? [23505-212]
```

- On update of parent removing a child:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "CHILD_ID"; SQL statement:
update child set child_id=null where child_id=? [23502-212]
```

There are some other minor issues, but it's mainly this that is giving me a hard time, thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you simply have your db generate the key with autoincrement?

Comment: @Stultuske So generationType.Auto instead of identity?

Comment: @Stultuske I tried and it throws Sequence "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE" not found; error. Either way, I think making it work with identity generationType would be the best approach

Answer (score 1):

In the end i "solved" it by basically making it bidirectional